# sox: Is there a way to change an effect value over time?

Tags: sox

I'm using sox to generate simple music. Is there a way to change an effect value over time? For example, I would like to change the level of the flange effect on a sample over a matter of seconds. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, SoX doesn’t support varying parameters like that. You might be interested in looking into [Ecasound](http://www.eca.cx/ecasound/) which has a stronger focus on interactivity.